# SQL: How to resolve "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to use cross-tab for my HRMS Attendance Report. As I used this SQL Script, I faced with this execution error said

> "(30 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

SQL script:

```
USE [KCLDB]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [hrms].[GET_ATTENDANCEREPORT]    Script Date: 05-Jul-18 10:41:42 AM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [hrms].[GET_ATTENDANCEREPORT]   
    @STARTDATE DATE,  
    @ENDDATE DATE  
AS 
BEGIN
    WITH DATERANGE AS  
    (  
        SELECT 
            DT = DATEADD(DD, 0, @STARTDATE)  
        WHERE  
            DATEADD(DD, 1, @STARTDATE) <= @ENDDATE  

        UNION ALL  

        SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, DT)  
        FROM DATERANGE  
        WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, DT) <= @ENDDATE  
    )  
    SELECT * 
    INTO #TMP_DATES  
    FROM DATERANGE   

    DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX)  

    SELECT @COLUMN = ISNULL(@COLUMN + ',', '') + '[' + CAST(CONVERT(DATE , T.DT) AS VARCHAR) + ']' 
    FROM #TMP_DATES T  

    DECLARE @Columns2 VARCHAR(MAX)  
    SET @Columns2 = SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(['+ CAST(CONVERT(DATE , DT) as varchar )+'],''N/A'') AS ['+CAST(CONVERT(DATE , DT) as varchar )+']' FROM #TMP_DATES GROUP BY DT FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)

    DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)  
    SET @QUERY = 'SELECT UserID, ' + @Columns2 +' FROM   
(  
SELECT A.UserID , B.DT AS DATE, A.[Clock], A.[Date] FROM hrms.AttendanceRecord A RIGHT OUTER JOIN #TMP_DATES B ON A.[Date]=B.DT   
) X  
PIVOT   
(  
MIN([Clock])  
FOR [Date] IN (' + @COLUMN + ')  
) P   
WHERE ISNULL(UserID,'''')<>''''  
'  

EXEC (@QUERY)  
DROP TABLE #TMP_DATES  

END  

---Execution Line

EXEC hrms.GET_ATTENDANCEREPORT @STARTDATE = '2018-05-01', @ENDDATE= '2018-05-30'
```

Comment: try `PRINT @QUERY` and see what is wrong with the query

Comment: Thank @Squirrel. I have tried to print it, and could not see any error or may be I am not really good at it. I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [hrms].[GET_ATTENDANCEREPORT]
    @STARTDATE DATE
    ,@ENDDATE  DATE
AS
BEGIN
    WITH
    [DATERANGE]
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            [DT] = DATEADD(DD, 0, @STARTDATE)
        WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, @STARTDATE) <= @ENDDATE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DATEADD(DD, 1, [DATERANGE].[DT])
        FROM
            [DATERANGE]
        WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, [DATERANGE].[DT]) <= @ENDDATE
    )
    SELECT
        [DATERANGE].[DT]
    INTO
        [#TMP_DATES]
    FROM
        [DATERANGE]

    DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT
        @COLUMN = ISNULL(@COLUMN + ',', '') + '[' + CAST(CONVERT(DATE, [T].[DT]) AS VARCHAR) + ']'
    FROM
        [#TMP_DATES] AS [T]

    DECLARE @Columns2 VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Columns2 = SUBSTRING(
                    (
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                               ',ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[' + CAST(CONVERT(DATE, [DT]) AS VARCHAR) + '],120),''N/A'') AS ['
                               + CAST(CONVERT(DATE, [DT]) AS VARCHAR) + ']'
                        FROM
                            [#TMP_DATES]
                        GROUP BY
                            [DT]
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    )
                    ,2
                    ,8000
                             )

    DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @QUERY = 'SELECT UserID, ' + @Columns2
                 + ' FROM   
(  
SELECT A.UserID , B.DT AS DATE2, A.[Clock], A.[Date] FROM hrms.AttendanceRecord A RIGHT OUTER JOIN #TMP_DATES B ON A.[Date]=B.DT   
) X  
PIVOT   
(  
MIN([Clock])  
FOR [Date] IN (' + @COLUMN + ')  
) P   
WHERE ISNULL(UserID,'''')<>''''  
'

    EXEC ( @QUERY )

    DROP TABLE [#TMP_DATES]
END
GO
---Execution Line
EXEC dbo.GET_ATTENDANCEREPORT @STARTDATE = '2018-05-01', @ENDDATE= '2018-05-30'
```

The issue was that since the column clock is datetime, all the columns in the pivot would be datetime, which you were trying to replace with "N/A" if they were null. "N/A" is not a valid datetime, hence the error.

Comment: Thank @SQLApostle. I solved it with this updated script.